# EFCore stuck on Get call

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a table that's very wide - 200 columns, but there's only one row (for local testing).

When I'm running my C# program (.Net Core), it's stuck on this line:

```
using DbServiceContext db = new();
WideTable wideTable = db.WideTable.FirstOrDefault(wide => wide.FkId == FkId);
```

(`DbServiceContext` is a subclass of `DbContext`)

Then after a long while (may 10 minutes), it shows this error in my debugger (Rider):
`java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out`

This format of calling EFCore works for other regular-sized tables, this is the only problematic one.

Env:

- MacOS
- MSSQL running on Docker

### Things I tried

1. I tailed `/var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog` in the docker container and it showed nothing related.
2. I increased the EFCore timeout to 2 minutes in `DbServiceContext`, by doing this in its constructor:
         `Database.SetCommandTimeout(120);`

What could be the issue here, and how do I debug it?

Comment: What makes sense wide => wide.FkId == FkId if you have only one record? You can only get the one record or nothing

Comment: @Serge: There are only one record by accident, during local testing.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Posting my debugging process and solution to benefit other people.

I did a human-powered binary search trying to find whether this issue is caused by the response size from the db, and if so, what's the maximum rows the response can include.

So I went into the model of WideTable, started commenting out almost all of if, leaving only a couple there, then made the call. The call succeeded, conclusion from this step:

1. No structural issues with the call
2. Either it's a size issue, or the annotation of one of the fields is wrong

Then I extracted the column names from the annotations in the model, compared them against the column names in the db table creation script. They matched, so that eliminated that source of error.

Then I started doing the binary search - commenting out half of the fields in the model, try the call again. Succeeded. Then try the binary search on the other half, succeeded. And so on.

Eventually, when I increase the (uncommented code) coverage from line 200 to line 205, it started to break again. Two possibilities can be drawn from this step:

1. The annotation for one of the lines is problematic between line 200 - 205;
2. 205 lines is the max size EFCore can handle

To invalid bullet 1, I kept line 200 - 205 uncommented, and commented out all other lines. Success. So that ruled out bullet 1.

Now we have arrived at the final conclusion that:

1. Yes, this is caused by the large size of the response
2. The solution is to break this table down into multiple tables